# Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) = 0$ for all rational $x$. Prove $f(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**Problem Statement:** Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) = 0$ for all rational $x$. Prove $f(x) = 0$.

The above is a question in Schaum's outline for calculus Chapter 7 Problem 15.

I am having trouble with the validity of the proof given by the author which reads as follows:

Consider any real number c. Since $f(x)$ is continuous at $c$, $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to c}} f(x) = f(c)$.

But, since there are rational numbers arbitrarily close to $c$, $f(x) = 0$ for values of $x$ arbitrarily close to $c$, and, therefore, $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to c}} f(x) = 0$. Hence, $f(c) = 0$.

To be more explicit, I suppose we should say since $c$ is any real number and the real numbers are assumed to be the domain of $f(x)$, we've shown that every real number in the domain of $f(x)$ maps to $0$.

---

The step I have a problem with is the idea of how identifying that there are rational numbers arbitrarily close to $c$ means $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to c}} f(x) = 0$, especially how this idea of "arbitrarily close" might translate into a more rigorous interpretation using the $\epsilon, \delta$-definition of limits.

What concerns me is the fact that the irrational numbers are not mentioned at all in this proof. The way I would have expected the proof to work would have been to show that the continuity of $f(x)$ and the fact that $f(x) = 0$ for all rational $x$ implies that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to c}} f(x) = 0$ for any irrational $c$.

I believe the part I am having the most trouble seeing is how we have shown that every irrational $c$, $f(c)=0$ by just examining the rational numbers. When I try to visualize a graph, I keep thinking that you can have an infinite number of irrational numbers between any two rational numbers, so we never really get two rational numbers that are "next" to each other.

This is confusing because it's different from how I normally interpret continuity in a graph such as $f(x) = x$, where I don't have to worry about there being gaps from one number to the next.

Is there a clearer way to think about all of this?

Comment: It is not really clear what is bothering you. Given any real $c$ there are rationals $q_n$ that converge to $c$ (take $q_n = {1 \over n} \lfloor n c \rfloor$ for example). Since $f$ is continuous, $f(q_n) \to f(c)$ and since $f(q_n) = 0$ we see that $f(c) = 0$. An irrational number is just a special case of a real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that $|x-y|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ this is continuity.

Now since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, for any irrational $x$ and any $\delta$ you can find a rational $q$ such that $|x-q|<\delta$ thus $|f(x)-f(q)|=|f(x)|<\epsilon$

Comment: Ok! I think I see: we have to have $f(x) = 0$ here because if not, we could choose $\epsilon < f(x)$ and then the function would not be continuous by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c$ be irrational and suppose, WLOG, $f(c) > 0$. Choose $\epsilon>0$ so that $f(c)-\epsilon>0$. If $f(c)<0$, we want $f(c)+\epsilon<0$. By definition of continuity, there exists $\delta$ such that for all $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, we have $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$, which implies $f(x)>f(c)-\epsilon$. But since rationals are dense, there's a rational number $r_1 \in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$ such that $0=f(r_1)>f(c)-\epsilon>0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Given, $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$. To show that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, it remains to show that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}^{c}$. (Note that $\mathbb{Q}^{c} = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$).

For the sake of contradiction, assume that there exists at least one point $x_0 \in \mathbb{Q}^{c}$ such that $f(x_0) \neq 0$.

Consider $(a_n)$ to be a sequence of rational numbers that converges to $x_0$ (we can have a sequence of rationals that converges to irrational because of the density property of rationals and irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$).

That is, $a_n \in \mathbb{Q} \space \forall \space n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $a_n \to x_0$ as $n \to \infty$

Hence, $f(a_n) = 0$ by hypothesis. Hence, $f(a_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. As $f$ is continuous, by the sequential criterion, we must have that $f(a_n) \to f(x_0)$ as $n \to \infty$. However, $f(x_0) \neq 0$ by assumption. This contradicts the continuity of $f$.

Thus, $f(x_0) = 0$, and as $x_0$ is arbitrary (for every sequence of rationals $a_n$ that converges to some irrational $x_0$, we must have $f(a_n) \to f(x_0)$ and $f(a_n) = 0$), it follows that $f(x_0) = 0 \space \forall \space x_0 \in \mathbb{Q}^{c}$.

As $\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{Q} \cup \mathbb{Q}^c$, we have that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.